# Perl. While loop behavior changes with seemingly inncocuous addition of command

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, while-loop

The following code reads a file that contains many lines. Some lines of the file contain four elements. Other lines contain only a first element, followed single spaces separated by tabs (it is a tab delimited file). That is, some lines are "full" and others are "blank".

The point of this script is to read the data file, find an instance of a blank line, then remember the immediately preceding line (a full line), scroll to find all consecutive blank lines until the next full line is reached. This set of lines, consecutive blank lines flanked by immediately preceding full line and immediately succeeding full line, is to be used by a subroutine that will apply linear interpolation to "fill in" the blank lines. The information in the flanking full lines for each set will be used in the interpolation step. The script was an answer to a previously posted question, and was provided kindly by user @Kenosis. It is duplicated here but with some very minor changes in its layout---not as neat as @Kenosis originally proposed. You can see this interaction at [Perl. Using until function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245511/perl-using-until-function#comment19786574_14245511)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;


die "usage: [ map positions file post SAS ]\n\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

my $mapfile = $ARGV[ 0 ];

open( my $FILE, "<$mapfile" );

my @file = <$FILE>;

for ( my $i = 1 ; $i < $#file ; $i++ ) #  $#file returns the index of the last element in @file
    {
     if ( $file[$i] =~ /(?:\t\s){3}/ ) # if a blank line is found
        {
         print $file[ $i - 1 ];    # print preceding line


         while ( $file[$i] =~ /(?:\t\s){3}/ and $i < $#file ) # keep printing so long as they are blank
                                                          # or end of file
             {
              #print $file[ $i++ ]    # one-column, blank line
             }

         print $file[ $i ];           # print the succeeding full line

       } # if

    } # for
```

The problem comes when I try to insert a modification.

```
my @collect = (); # array collects a current set of consecutive lines needed for linear interpolation

my @file = <$FILE>;

for ( my $i = 1 ; $i < $#file ; $i++ ) #  $#file returns the index of the last element in @file
    {
     if ( $file[$i] =~ /(?:\t\s){3}/ ) # if a blank line is found
        {
         print $file[ $i - 1 ];    # print preceding line
         push( @collect, $file[ $i - 1 ] );

         while ( $file[$i] =~ /(?:\t\s){3}/ and $i < $#file ) # keep printing so long as they are blank
                                                          # or end of file
             {
              #print $file[ $i++ ];    # one-column, blank line
              push( @collect, $file[ $i++ ] )
             }

         print $file[ $i ];           # else, succeeding full line
         push( @collect, $file[ $i ] );

       } # if

    } # for
```

The culprit is in the while loop. Adding the `push` command there changes the behavior of the script. The script is no longer printing all the lines as the first script above. Why does adding that command change how the script is supposed to work?

Comment: There is no need to explicitly open `$ARGV[0]`.  That's what `<>` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do in that `push` line?

It includes the expression `$i++`, which adds 1 to the value of `$1`, so each iteration of that `while` loop will be jumping down another line in the file.

Do you just mean `$i + 1`?

Comment: ahhh, I am incrementing, and I don't want to.  I am just trying to collect into an array all the statements that are printed in a single run through the loop. That set of lines will go to a subroutine for linear interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really adding a second line of code that increments `$i`?  `$i += 1` is not the same as `$i += 2`